надо чтоб Router работал как dp как сделать это в PyCharm

надо чтоб Router работал как dp как сделать это в PyCharm
from aiogram import  F , Router
from aiogram.types import  Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

router = Router()


@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Добрый день,Это бот команды [PG]')


@dp.message(Command('help'))
async def cmd_help(message:Message):
    await message.answer('Скоро тех поддержка с вами свяжется ')


@dp.message (F.text == 'Проблема решена')
async def nice(message:Message):
    await message.answer('Оцените помощь от 1 до 10 ')


начни отсюда - [ask]

Вам нужно использовать router вместо dp иначе зачем вы его импортируете.
from aiogram import F , Router
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command

router = Router()

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Добрый день,Это бот команды [PG]')


@router.message(Command('help'))
async def cmd_help(message:Message):
    await message.answer('Скоро тех поддержка с вами свяжется ')


@router.message (F.text == 'Проблема решена')
async def nice(message:Message):
    await message.answer('Оцените помощь от 1 до 10 ')

